# Do humans have a loud sound avoidance reflex?

Tags: hearing, reflex-impulse

I accidentally played music wearing earphones at top volume, and felt maybe half a second of pain before I seemingly involuntarily swatted the earphones to the ground. I don't remember even having time to think about the loud noise before the earphones were on the ground, and it left me thinking, do humans have a reflex to "swat" away loud noises from the ears?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonic_weapon

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing sounds like a [startle response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Startle_response). The startle response, along with the [vestibular-occular reflex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vestibulo%E2%80%93ocular_reflex) and [acoustic reflex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_reflex), and are often thought of as reflexes, despite not involving a [reflex arc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflex_arc) where a sensory neuron synapses with the spinal cord allowing for motor responses to occur without the signal reaching the brain. The startle response involves a number of brain structures and therefore, even though it is an unconscious response, in the strictest sense, it is not a reflex.

Comment: There's a subsection on that startle response wiki about the "acoustic startle response," which seems almost similar to what I'm looking for